# Correct escaping for Where clause in dynamic procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, escaping

I am pretty new to dynamic procedure and am trying to use something like the below in a Where clause there.

I have covered the rest of the procedure but have an issue with the below.

What would the correct escaping (quotes) look like in this case to cover the variable inputs? Also, I am not sure how to handle the part "`R.@searchCategory`" as here I need to add the "R.".

**SQL Query :**

```
WHERE       ' + @selection + ' = ''closed'' AND (R.logStatus LIKE ''%Completed%'' OR R.logStatus LIKE ''%Closed%'')
AND
    (
            (
                ' + @searchCategory + ' <> ''dateRec'' AND R.' + @searchCategory + ' LIKE ''%' + @searchTerm + '%''
            )
            OR
            (
                ' + @searchCategory  + ' = ''dateRec'' AND CAST(R.dateRec AS DATE) LIKE ''%' + @searchTerm + '%''
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easier and use `REPLACE` and `QUOTENAME`

```
SET @sql = ...
'WHERE @selection = ''closed'' ' +
'      AND (R.logStatus LIKE ''%Completed%'' ' +
'           OR R.logStatus LIKE ''%Closed%'') ' +
'      AND ( ' +
'            (@searchCategoryText <> ''dateRec'' ' +
'             AND R.@searchCategoryColumn LIKE ''%'' + @searchTerm + ''%'' ' +
'            ) ' +
'            OR ' +
'            (@searchCategoryText = ''dateRec'' ' +
'             AND CAST(R.dateRec AS DATE) LIKE ''%'' + @searchTerm + ''%'' ' +
'            ) ' +
'          ) ';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@selection', QUOTENAME(@selection, ''''));
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@searchCategoryText', QUOTENAME(@searchcategory, ''''));  
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@searchCategoryColumn', QUOTENAME(@searchcategory)); 
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@searchTerm', QUOTENAME(@searchTerm, ''''));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes sense and looks like the more professional approach in this case so I'll go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

you have to separate out each whenever you add your variable like

```
WHERE ' + @selection +'= ''closed'' AND (R.logStatus LIKE ''%Completed%'' OR R.logStatus LIKE ''%Closed%'')
AND
    (
            (
                ' + @searchCategory +' <> ''dateRec'' AND R.' + @selection +'@searchCategory LIKE ''%' + ' + @searchTerm+'%''
            )
            OR
            (
                ' + @searchCategory  +'= ''dateRec'' AND CAST(R.dateRec AS DATE) = ' + @searchTerm +'
            )
    )
```

Still you got error then make direct query on which you make dynamic latter. i.e.

```
declare @searchCategory nvarchar(100) = 'abc'
select * from table where colname = @searchCategory
```

Run this and check the result properly come, now you just add into string here and your query ready to execute , simple.

Comment: Thanks for this. This does not look correct when I add it to my stored procedure.

Comment: "R.@searchCategory" this show that you replace @searchcategory with actual value. what you do, just make first direct query with actual parmaeter and then create this.